# How to build multi color tab button in Ext JS?

Tags: javascript, sass, extjs5, sencha-cmd

Good day!

There is a project we are working, fontend based on **Extjs 5.1** where we have to implement multi color `TabItem` using `Ext.tab.Panel` not only the body but also the **Tab Button/Header**. We are able to change the body style of each `TabItem` but unable to change **Tab Button/Header**. Unable to set any selector for each **Tab Button/Header**.

Here is the plain example but we have to implement it in Extjs **MVVM**

```
Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    width     : 300,
    height    : 200,
    activeTab : 0,
    items     : [{
        title : 'Tab 1',
        html  : 'A simple tab'
    }, {
        title : 'Tab 2',
        html  : 'Another one'
    }],
    renderTo  : Ext.getBody()
});
```

Would you please kind enough to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple, just add `cls` property under `tabConfig` by which you can maintain the style separately from your `scss` or `css` file. Here is the example :-

```
Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
    width     : 300,
    height    : 200,
    activeTab : 0,
    items     : [{
        title     : 'Tab 1',
        cls       : 'tab-item-01-body',
        tabConfig : {
            tooltip   : 'Tab 1',
            cls       : 'tab-item-01-head'
        },
        html      : 'A simple tab',
    }, {
        title     : 'Tab 2',
        cls       : 'tab-item-02-body',
        tabConfig : {
            tooltip   : 'Tab 2',
            cls       : 'tab-item-02-head'
        },
        html      : 'Another one'
    }],
    renderTo  : Ext.getBody()
});
```